# How to add ORDER to an MDX based parameter

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

How can I change the following data set query to order by Employee Name

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
[Employee].[Employee Name].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
[Employee].[Employee ID].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
[Employee].[Employee ID].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT 
{[Measures].[ParameterCaption]
, [Measures].[ParameterValue]
, [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , 
[Employee].[Employee ID].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ReportingCurrencyReportingCurrency, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@PROJGROUPProjGroup, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@CompanyCompanyAccounts, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [ACTIVITY])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the ORDER function - although I'll need to test as I'm unsure this will work:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
[Employee].[Employee Name].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
[Employee].[Employee ID].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
[Employee].[Employee ID].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
SELECT 
{[Measures].[ParameterCaption]
, [Measures].[ParameterValue]
, [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , 
ORDER(
  [Employee].[Employee ID].ALLMEMBERS,
  [Measures].[ParameterCaption],
  BDESC
)ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@ReportingCurrencyReportingCurrency, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@PROJGROUPProjGroup, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@CompanyCompanyAccounts, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [ACTIVITY])))
```

Comment: How would I add second sort. Sort by ParameterLevel and then ParmeterCaption?

Comment: @LCM did the sort in my answer sort by caption ok?